# How to design custom labels for flutter tabs using box decoration?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to know how to make the following tabs UI in flutter using box decoration?

[image: Fluter tab design]

So far I have achieved following UI with the help of  applying shape decoration to  indicator using the following code

```
indicator: ShapeDecoration(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                    topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              ),
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  begin: Alignment(0.5, 0),
                                  end: Alignment(0.5, 1),
                                  colors: [
                                    const Color(0xff494949),
                                    const Color(0xff3a3a3a)
                                  ])),
                        ),
```

[image: actual tabs]

Comment: what have you got so far.sample code?

Comment: I have added the code and a screenshot of the  UI looks as of now.